# Can Sacrificial Construct be uses to prevent the trash of cards like Clone Chip or Shiv?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Sacrificial Construct](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01048) says:

> [Trash]: Prevent an installed program or an installed piece of hardware from being trashed.

Does this mean it can be used to prevent the trashing of cards like [Clone Chip](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03038) or [Shiv](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08066) when you activate their trash ability?

Comment: To whoever is downvoting this - This is a very common question by new players when seeing this card, and has not been yet asked on this site. Stack Exchange encourages the sharing of knowledge this way, even going so far to allow the poster of the question to answer it while asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

While you are free to use [Sacrificial Construct](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01048) to prevent sacrificing your [Clone Chip](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03038) or your [Shiv](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08066), this means the cost was not paid and nothing happens, other than the Sacrificial Construct being trashed.

Compare Clone Chip with [Acacia](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/21021): Acacia will still work and can be saved by Sacrificial Construct, Clone Chip will not, since Clone Chip's cost was prevented.

[From the official FAQ:](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)

> If the cost of a paid ability requires a card to be trashed, then preventing that card from being trashed prevents the cost from being paid and the paid ability does not resolve.